# How to secure postfix to find out whether the emails are coming really from the sender?

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, email-server

Is it possible to secure postfix in a way, that incoming emails are checked on whether the email comes really from the sender?

Is that possible to write php script and chose a sender, like the mail is really coming from the sender and what are the possibilities for postfix to find out that this mail is not actually coming from the real sender?

What I have found out and activated are the options

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
unknown_address_reject_code = 554
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unknown_client
unknown_client_reject_code = 554
```

Please mention, whether I have missed out on any points!

Comment: If you enable SPF and DKIM checks you may get some more assurance about this. But I'll leave it to people more proficient with postfix on how to do this. Your real problem is that SMTP does not guarantee the validity of the sender, so there may be cases where certain recipients may need to demand emails be digitally signed by the sender.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that SMTP mail was designed to be pretty much like regular mail. You write a message, put it in an envelope, write the recipient address on the envelope), write the sender name on the envelope, hand it over to the postman and off it goes (sorry no stamp here). Even if you write the wrong sender (purposely or not) the message will reach its recipient. What is in the envelope may not reveal the true sender.

SPF helps a lot identify the sender DOMAIN but there are no 100% guarantees. The target of SPF was pretty much SPAM rather than fix this SMTP feature. The idea behind SPF is that a domain will say which SMTP servers are valid and the recipient will have a way (DNS record) to check that information.
DKIM on the other hand guarantees the source DOMAIN (not the user) by actually digitally signing the envelope/header. Digital signatures/certificates are the high price you need to pay for this. You can find information on how to implement these on the [Postfix site](http://www.postfix.org)

Of course there are countless other things that can go wrong in the above UNLESS you use encrypted communcations (like a man in the middle interception).